# WPF animated GIF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to use library from https://github.com/XamlAnimatedGif/WpfAnimatedGif/ to solve my animation gif using wpf. I wrote some code to bind the image to the Image, but it is not working.

WPF:

```
<Image gif:ImageBehavior.RepeatBehavior="Forever"
           gif:ImageBehavior.AnimatedSource="{Binding ElementName=WpfAnimation, Path=ImageStatus}"/>
```

Code Behind:

```
// Image status property
        public readonly DependencyProperty ImageStatusProperty;
    public ImageSource ImageStatus
    {
        get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(ImageStatusProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ImageStatusProperty, value); }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ImageStatus = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Images/anipier_e0.gif", UriKind.Relative));

    }
```

Error:

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233087
  Message='The invocation of the constructor on type 'WpfAnimation.MainWindow' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.' Line number '4' and line position '9'.
  Source=PresentationFramework
InnerException: System.ArgumentNullException
       HResult=-2147467261
       Message=Value cannot be null.
```

Thank you.

Comment: I search it from internet, http://www.animatedgif.net/animals/bugs/anipier_e0.gif

Comment: Hi all, I have added the error section in my question, tq.

Comment: Looks like your image Uri is broken. Make sure the image is in an "Images" folder relative to the location of your exe (something like WpfAnimation\bin\Debug\Images\anipier_e0.gif).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something is wrong with your binding : AnimatedSource is binding to an element named "WpfAnimation".  You should bind the AnimatedSource to a property of your DataContext. If WpfAnimation is similar to LayoutRoot, use an expression like this :

```
<Image gif:ImageBehavior.RepeatBehavior="Forever"
           gif:ImageBehavior.AnimatedSource="{Binding ElementName=WpfAnimation, Path=DataContext.ImageStatus}"/>
```

Also, check the Debug/Output for binding errors, that the animated gif is a resource, that your Uri is valid, and that a DataContext is associated to your view.

**EDIT:**

Looks like there is a exception in the view constructor.

Comment: The animated gif is compile in resource.

Comment: check the constructor. There is an exception when you load the gif.